# Jpa não cria coluna @lob

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa-2.0, blob

Estou mapeando um campo `@lob` para gravar imagem em uma tabela, mas o jpa cria a tabela, mas não cria a coluna. Criei a coluna manualmente no MYSQL, mas aí não persiste os bytes também.

Minha Entidade:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_IMAGEM")
public class Imagem  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Lob
@Column(name = "IMAGE_CONTENT")
private byte[] imagemByte;//não cria somente essa coluna, se crio manualmente, não persiste e nem Lê essa coluna

//getters e setters
}
```

Meu persistence.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="primary">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/meuDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

No console ela cria a tabela, mas não a coluna blob.

> 15:23:28 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) Hibernate:
>   create table TB_IMAGEM (ID_IMAGEM bigint not null auto_increment
>   primary key (ID_IMAGEM))

Estou utilizando a JPA 2.1, biblioteca hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar

Estou utilizando MYSQL 5.5, Hibernate 4.1.1

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>projeto</artifactId>
        <groupId>br.com.projeto</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>projeto-ejb</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <name>projeto: EJB Module</name>
    <url>http://wildfly.org</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <dependencies>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.projeto</groupId>
            <artifactId>projeto-comuns</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test scope dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
        <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA) 
            JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>            
        </dependency>
        <!-- conversao para pdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>documents4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>teste</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.arquillian.container}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.arquillian.container}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Qual versão do Hibernate você está utilizando? E do MySQL? Se estiver usando o Maven, edite sua pergunta e coloque o seu `pom.xml`, por favor.

Comment: Estou utilizando MYSQL 5.5, Hibernate 4.1.1. Obrigado.

Comment: Talvez seja algum problema com suas dependências. Você tem declarada a seguinte dependência `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`, porém JPA 2.1 só é suportado pelo Hibernate a partir da versão 4.3.

Comment: Vou utilizar a versão do hibernate mais nova e te falo.

Comment: Atualizei a dependencia para o jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate e ele atualizou toda a dependencia do hibernate para 4.3, mas mesmo assim ainda não funcionou.

Comment: Tem alguma ideia do que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize

```
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
@Column(length = 10000)
```

No meu caso, o type utilizado foi TextType, na seguinte documentação você encontrará o tipo de dado correspondente para seu caso. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/type/package-summary.html